# $L = \{ a^{j!} \mid j \geq1\}$ is not context free by pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

How I use the pumping lemma to prove that the language $L = \{ a^{j!} \mid j \geq1\}$ is not context-free?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that a language is not context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free)

Comment: Note that this language is [not regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/87441). As the language is over a one letter alphabet this is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $L$ is context free. Then, by pumping lemma, there exist two integers $h \ge 1$ and $1 \le x \le \min\{h!, c_L\}$, where $c_L$ is a constant depending on $L$, that satisfy the following:

- $a^{h!} \in L$
- $a^{h!-x} a^{xn} \in L$ for every $n \ge 0$.<sup>1</sup>

Now you only need to show that, for some value of $n$, $a^{h!-x} a^{xn} \not\in L$.
Equivalently, you want to find a value of $n$ (possibly depending on $h$) such that
$h! + (n-1)x$ cannot be written as $j!$ for any integer $j \ge 1$.

For example, if $h = 1$ then $x=1$ so you can pick $n=0$ to obtain $h! + (n-1)x = 0$.

When $h \ge 2$, you can pick $n=2$ so that $h! + (n-1)x = h! + x$, which is not a factorial of an integer as the following inequalities show:
$$
h! < h! + x \le 2 \cdot h! < (h+1)!
$$

---

1. This is a consequence of the general form of the pumping lemma and of the fact that all the words in your language contain only the character *a*.